# CarouFredSel - Working with div

Tags: html, css, slider, carousel, caroufredsel

I have added the CarouFredSel plugin into my website, and followed this example: http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/2/. The slider is working as it should, by showing one image at left and another on the right and rotating. But now I need to display divs that contain text and maybe image. This will be some sort of article scrolling, and then the scroll-function gets broken.

Now it dosen't scroll as it should. Any idea on how to fix it? Or do you know of any other slider that have the same design but works better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used something similar on one project that I worked on.
Caroufredsel slides all children in initialized container and it should work without any problems.

Here is example HTML structure:

```
<div class="slideshow_container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="slideshow">
            <div class="slide">
               Slide content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then initialize the slider

```
$('.slideshow').carouFredSel(options);
```

You can see working example on here:
**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ma8Wj/3/)**

Comment: Thanks for answer and demo. I will need to test this out, but your example looks great :)